# Anyone having problems with 2.78 and GTX 660 - specifically baking?

Tags: baking, windows

I have gotten zero replies on this and for the life of me don't know why. I'm an intermediate user who has tried everything to get a Combined bake to show up on my image map in Texture mode. After the bake, all that appears is a dissipated wash of color (a lot of white mixed in - and no my environment and lamps aren't overly bright, also no AO, so i'm befuddled). Could it be my NVidia (GTX 660) and driver (375.95) are not handshaking with 2.78? I did hear others were having problems with 78 and some NV cards. Can anyone confirm they're having baking problems with this specific card and/or driver? I'm using Win7 with 24GB of ram. I even went through a bunch of baking tutorials just to refresh myself on baking to make sure it wasn't me. Still, nothing. I can't believe i can't get a simple baked texture to appear on a simple object in Texture mode, just as it does in Rendered mode (close anyway). Has something changed in 2.78a in how Blender handles shadows/lighting, maybe even baking? I also use BakeTool - same result. PLEASE, can someone help me with this because i'm literally going to have to quit using Blender, maybe 3D altogether since i can't afford Houdini. If you have any pertinent info i'd be more than appreciative.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. If you have extra information please update the original question by using the 'edit' link below it.

Comment: 10-4, sorry Ray. It's just that since my post was only up for like one day with no responses, i thought i should reword the question so the post would recycle to the top of the stack ..NPI :).  I DID edit it previously, but that didn't send it back through. Anyway, i'll stop posting.